# How do I save multiple UIImages in FileManager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager

I'm saving the image set by the user in FileManager. Then, I gotta retrieve these images and populate a UITableView. However, how can I save multiple different images then recover it all and present on my UITableView?

The error I'm facing is that when I save the image, then I retrieve it I just got a single UIImage, instead of multiple different images. Even though I save another different image, it just got replaced instead of adding another one. So, doing this way I can't populate a UITableView, because I always get a single UIImage instead of multiple saved images.

***This is the function to save the Images***

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
        let data = UIImage.pngData(image)
        guard let directory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) as NSURL else {
            return false
        }
        do {
            try data()?.write(to: (directory.appendingPathComponent("fileName2.png")?.absoluteURL)!)
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }
```

***That's how I'm saving the UIImage***

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.imagePreview.image = image
            self.namePreview.text = self.textFieldNome.text

           //Saving Image
            let savingImage = saveImage(image: image)
                print("\(savingImage)")


        }
        self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

***This is the function retrieve the images***

```
func getSavedImage(named: String) -> UIImage? {
        if let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) {
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent(named).path)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

***ViewController: That's how I'm trying to retrieve the Images***

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let image = getSavedImage(named: "fileName2.png") {

            print(image)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your title implies there is an issue with the code you posted. But then the start of your question is basically asking how to modify the presented code to work with multiple images. Which is it?

Comment: Hello @rmaddy! Thanks for advise me, I just reformulated my question

Comment: Your `saveImage` function needs a "name" parameter just like your `getSaveImage` function.

Comment: @rmaddy I forgot to paste the getSaveImage function, I just updated the question.

Comment: @rmaddy The error I'm facing is that when I save the image, then I retrieve it I just got a single UIImage, instead of multiple different images. Even though I save another different image, it just got replaced instead of adding another one. Did you get me?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is here :)**

```
import Photos

let imagesArray = [UIImage]()

for image in imagesArray{  //multiple image array 
    let objImage: UIImage = image
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: 
objImage)
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if success {
            // Saved
        }else {
            // failed
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hello, so this is the way I save the data, correct? How do I retrieve the images in another screen?